# Julia metaprogramming: "ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression $"

Tags: julia

Why am I getting the error message below? (I'm fairly new to metaprogramming in Julia.) Thanks.

```
julia> d = :e
:e

julia> macroexpand(:(b.$d))
:(b.e)

julia> macroexpand(:($d.c))
:(e.c)

julia> macroexpand(:(b.$d.c))
ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression $

julia> macroexpand(:(b.$(d).c))
ERROR: unsupported or misplaced expression $
```

Comment: looks like a bug that is fixed on 0.4, I get `julia> macroexpand(:(b.$d.c))
:(b.e.c)`   Output of `versioninfo()`: `Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+4630
Commit f299fed (2015-05-04 14:29 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
`

Comment: what about just `:(b.$d.c)` instead of `macroexpand(...)`?

Comment: @ptb Thanks for the comments. `ex = :(b.$d.c)` throws the same error as above unfortunately. Must have something to do with the assignment operation.

Comment: There's something really weird going on here. `macroexpand` shouldn't be needed and you shouldn't be getting that error message. It seems that `ex = :((b.$d).c)` will do what you want, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug, issue filed here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/10997

It has been fixed since. As indicated in the comments on the question, there are some hacky workarounds if you're stuck on an unfixed Julia version, but hopefully you can upgrade.